# Can this work in CSS?

Tags: css, xhtml

I want to have hover styles on a link, but *not* on a span which is a child of that link. I've never done it before, but I tried this

```
.properties #content table th a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.properties #content table th a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.properties #content table th a:hover span.sort-direction {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The hover underline works great, but it still underlines the span. I guess this is because an underline of the anchor element will stretch to fit the span, I think.

What would be a workaround? I want the span to be a link too. Maybe a combination of `position: relative` on the anchor and `position: absolute` on the span?

Comment: Since valid HTML can't have 2 elements with the same ID, you can make your selectors more efficient by removing the `.properties ` in all cases, just a tip :)

Comment: The CSS looks okay. Can you point to a test page?

Comment: I used properties as a class of my body element for targeting different pages.

Comment: @Nick: Actually, when the same CSS is to be used across multiple pages then you may very well want to only select `#content` when it is inside `.properties`.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - While correct, still better to use a more selective ID in that case, as IDs are much more efficiently used by the browser.  Just a matter of taste I guess, but long selectors rarely make life easier IMO.

Comment: The proper way to do it, since `.properties` is a class of `body` element, and there can be only one `body` element, would be to make it an id: `#properties`. Long selectors can make life easier in this case, because the css will be cached for all pages, and it will be easier to template one `#content` across different pages.

Comment: Well, I like to use class for my MVC projects. Consider this in the controller (PHP) `$this->bodyClass[] = 'home';` and then in the view `<body class="<?php echo implode(' ', $bodyClass); ?>">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put the anchor node in its own span, and then set the `text-decoration: underline` on it.

```
.properties #content table th a:hover span.header {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any HTML, I made a simplified example:

CSS

```
.properties a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.properties a:hover span.hovered {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="properties">
 <a href="#"><span class="hovered">Hello</span> Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: oh oops, I see you answered your own question... I guess I should have paid attention

Comment: Sorry, I thought the HTML was self explanatory. But it always helps to see it and not have to make assumptions, I'll admit.

Comment: LOL I'll admit, I thought you were just adding more CSS to your question and not providing an answer, so I didn't look at it right away.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting quirk. Since the width of the `a` element includes the `span`, the underline goes across the whole `a` link. An underline value of `none` does not "blank out" that underline. You could get the effect you want this way (presuming your background is white):

```
.properties #content table th a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.properties #content table th a:hover span.sort-direction {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

If you have a non-solid background this may not look ideal. You may be better off adding an additional `span` element.